# swift: Completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview

So, I have method `loadData()` which download datas from [parse.com](http://parse.com)

[image]

And I should present all images show in table view.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ReusableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LeaguesTableViewCell

    loadData { (success) in
        if success {
            cell.leagueImage.image = UIImage(data: self.leaguesImage[indexPath.row])
            cell.leagueNameLabel.text = self.leagues[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String
        } else {
            cell.leagueNameLabel.text = "Wait"
        }
    }


    return cell

}
```

Its didn't work. I call my function in `viewDidLoad()` but its not correct too, table view is empty.

[image]
Cuz my array is empty

My

Comment: Describe "Didn't Work".. Also, are you "locking" the array properly before inserting into it?

Comment: It's just don't go to method cellForAtIndexPath, table view is empty

Comment: If the cells are not showing up, your delegate implementation of `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is incorrect (returning 0). Either that or you never set the tableView dataSource and delegate.

Comment: We need a bit more information...what thread is `loadData` called on?

Comment: You need to reload the tableview using `self.tableView.reloadData` method to show the updated view upon receiving the data.

Comment: Also, please don't post screen snapshots of code. Post the actual code. If you need to include an image to show something about the IDE, feel free to do so, but also include the code, itself.

Answer (score 3):

The basic procedure for loading data into a UITableView is:

1. Load the data
2. Reload the table view
3. Return the number of sections in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method: In your case there is only 1 section.
4. Return the number of rows in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`: In your case return the number of leagues if the data is loaded. If the data is not loaded then return 1 so that the table view has at least one row to display the "Wait" message.
5. Create and populate the cells from the data: Use `leagues` and `leaguesImage`.

Example:

```
private var loaded = false   

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loaded = false

    loadData() { success in
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock() {
            self.loaded = success
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int {
    if loaded {
        return leagues.count 
    }
    else {
        return 1
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ReusableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LeaguesTableViewCell

    if loaded {
        cell.leagueImage.image = UIImage(data: self.leaguesImage[indexPath.row])
        cell.leagueNameLabel.text = self.leagues[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String
    }
    else {
        cell.leagueNameLabel.text = "Wait"
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: This is largely correct, though you should not wait to retrieve the images before showing anything. He should perform his `Leagues` fetch (which should be fairly quick), but _not_ retrieve the images. And then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should lazily retrieve the image. Images can be big and we don't know how many he's retrieving, so it could be slow to retrieve all of them, especially since we only need the first screenful of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set delegate and datasource first. If you have separate datasource other than view controller, retain it otherwise you will not get any callback.

Comment: class LeaguesTableViewController: UITableViewController , I don't need anything

Comment: Yeah, i do this after every-changing (didSet)